# Spring boot externalize config properties/messages on Java annotations

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-boot, annotations

Is there a way to read text from external properties file in spring without using the `@Value` annotation. Ex: application.properties

```
var.foo="hello"
```

I can inject it in a spring bean using

```
@Value("${var.foo}") String value;
```

as a class variable. Is there a way to include this property without using the `@Value` annotation. Something like how JSR bean validation does.

```
@NotNull(message={custom.notnull})
```

and you externalize this property value in **ValidationMessages.properties** file.

Example, if I have a resource(web component) class, and if I have to use Swagger annotations to document them,

```
@controller
@path("/")
@Api(description = "User Resource API")
public class UserResource {

    @Path("/users")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "returns user details", notes = "some notes")
    public User getUser() {

        return new User(123, "Joe", "Montana");
    }
}
```

and the model,

```
@ApiModel("user model")
public class User {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "This represents user id")
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    ...
}
```

How do you externalize this string/sentences/messages to an external properties file. I think this applies to general Java annotations and spring and not specific to Swagger. The reason I specified Swagger is, if just like hibernate validation Java library has the option of specifying these messages in an external ValidationMessages.properties file and spring knows by default to pick it up (or can be configured).

Does Swagger provide such an option? If it does not, how do I setup one?

Underlying problem is, I don't want to clutter my code/logic with documentation related data(meta data).

Comment: You need to provide more details on your use case as to why you can't or don't want to use the `@Value` annotation. There is the other area of Spring around i18n support which uses the messages.properties to allow certain areas to leverage token replacement with language specific text.

Comment: hi @shawn.. thanks for your response. let me edit this question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this unless the underlying implementation of the annotations you're using either come with their own standard for i18n (like `ValidationMessages.properties`), or support Spring's `MessageSource`.

In the case of the latter alternative, all you should have to do is to add your key/value pairs inside a `messages.properties` file and let the framework do the rest:

**messages.properties**

```
my.validation.error.message=Something went terribly wrong!
```

**SomeClass.java**

```
@MySpringCompatibleValidationAnnotation("my.validation.error.message")
private String someVariable;
```

Bottom line is, depending on the framework you're trying to use, it may or may not support this out-of-the-box.

Now, as far as Swagger goes, i18n support for documentation was proposed as a new feature, but it was shut down or put on hold while they put some more thought into how it should be implemented. See https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/274 for more details.

Comment: thanks Thomas for the reply.. I feel Swagger annotations without externalizing the values for various annotation properties adds too much clutter to the code (models, resources...).

Answer (score 2):

Using the `@Value("${property}")` annotation to inject configuration properties can sometimes be cumbersome, so spring boot introduced the `@ConfigurationProperties`, this should be the solution what you want.

[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) is the reference doc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a placeholder when you declare a bean in your configuration file.Here you can try an example :
https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Spring Boot then you can try this method, without doing any special configuration

```
@environment.getProperty('property')
```